# After closing Modal box how to perform operations on the browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I am writing a `TestNg` script where I want to close the modal box and perform the operations on the browser. I am able to close the modal
but not able to do anything on the browser.

```
 driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys(userName1);
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password1);
            driver.findElement(By.id("Login")).click();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            switchtoLightining();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("App Launcher")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("ICIX")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Document Library")).click();
            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("vfFrameId")));
            driver.findElement(By.id("btn_AddDocument")).click();
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ddTemplate")))
                    .selectByVisibleText("GFSI Certification");
            driver.findElement(By.id("createButton")).click();
            // Get the current window handle
            String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            // Get the list of window handles
            ArrayList<String> tabs2 = new ArrayList<String>(
                    driver.getWindowHandles());
            System.out.println("size is:" + tabs2.size());
             driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0));
    Robot rb = new Robot();
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);                 

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            // Click on the upload button
            // Switch to the parent old window
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='slds-button slds-button--brand slds-m-horizontal--small']")).click();*/
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='uploadButton']")).click();
```

Comment: what error msg are you getting

Comment: I'm getting this error- org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='uploadButton']"}
Command duration or timeout: 25.13 seconds

Comment: hi i am confused here in your code // Get the current window handle
            String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle(); here you are taking the parent window handle right and then  you are switching to  driver.switchTo().window(tabs2.get(0)); //but 0 index is again for the parent window hence infact you are not switching any window

Comment: can you please copy pate the complete source code of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per code provided before switching to that model window you are inside a frame. so i am expecting you may need to switch to frame after

```
          driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

to click on that upload button.

If upload button is not in frame, just see the gettitle or getcurrenturl will getting you parent or winHandleBefore to cross driver switched to window or not. If driver switched to winHandleBefore correctly then issue with your upload element locator. please check that once.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: Thanks. You are correct button is inside the frame, switching to the frame worked for me.driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("vfFrameId")));